# ¿Como puedo incrementar datos en un bucle for en php?

Tags: php

tengo que cada vez que doy click en añadir este siga aumentando los datos, ahora solo consigo que cada vez que doy click se actualice pero no guarda  el anterior el php es el siguiente

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if(empty($_SESSION['producto'])){
  $_SESSION['producto']=array();   
  }
  // esto viene de js por trae el id del producto y la cantidad 
  ingresada
  if(isset($_GET['p'])){
   $_SESSION['producto']['id'] = $_GET['p']; 
  }
  if(isset($_GET['c'])){
   $_SESSION['producto']['can'] = $_GET['c']; 
  }
  //incremento i en 2 para que ponga en la misma linea la cantidad y el 
 id
for ($i=1; $i < count($_SESSION['producto']); $i+=2){

  $cab = $_SESSION['producto']['can'];
 $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
 id='.$_SESSION['producto']['id'].'');
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
            echo '<center><td>';

           echo '<center><input type="number" name="ja" class="la" 
         value="'.$cab.'""></center>';
            echo '</td></center>';
```

esto obtengo con esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero como digo no me deja aumentar datos solo pone los datos del ultimo click que doy

Comment: Según veo asignas a la misma variable el nuevo valor y asi cada actualizacion. Con vierte el ID de producto en índice del arreglo para que solo se sobre escriba si es el mismo.** $_SESSION['producto'][ $_GET['p']] = $can**

Comment: no te entendi me puedes eplicar mejor

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te ayude

```
if(empty($_SESSION['producto'])){
    $_SESSION['producto']=array();   
}

// esto viene de js por trae el id del producto y la cantidad ingresada
if(isset($_GET['p']) && isset($_GET['c']))
{
    // Si existe el producto incrementar la cantidad
    if(isset($_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['p']]))
    {
        $_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['p']] = $_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['p']] + (int)$_GET['c'];
    }
    // Si no existe asignar la cantidad obtenida
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['p']] = (int)$_GET['c'];
    }
}

// Listar la session
foreach($_SESSION['producto'] as $producto => $cantidad){

    $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE id='.$producto.'');
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
        echo '<center><td>';
        echo '<center><input type="number" name="ja" class="la" value="'.$cantidad.'""></center>';
        echo '</td></center>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo simulando un carrito de compra, que guarda los productos en un array:

```
<?php
// Imaginemos que tienes el siguiente array, simulando un carrito, donde 
// añadiste 2 productos: "foo" y "baz", cada un con una cantidad de 1.
$array = [
    "foo" => 1,
    "baz" => 1,
];

// Ahora quieres comprar una segunda unidad del producto "foo"
// Entonces intentas hacer             
foreach($array as $key => $value ) {
    if ($key === "foo") {
        $array[$key] = $array[$key] + 1;
    }
}

// Si trazas el contenido del array, ahora la cantidad del producto "foo"
// se ha incrementado en 1
print_r($array);
/*
Array
(
    [foo] => 2
    [baz] => 1
)
*/

// Podrías crear una función. Siguiente la misma estructura:
function changeQuantity($arr_products, $product_name, $quantity=1)
{
    foreach($arr_products as $key => $value ) {
        if ($key === $product_name) {
            $arr_products[$key] = $arr_products[$key] + $quantity;

            return $arr_products;
        }
    }

    return $arr_products;
}

// Ahora puedes añadir al siguiente array:
$array = [
    "foo" => 1,
    "baz" => 1,
];

// Un producto de esta manera:
$array = changeQuantity($array, "foo");

// o esta otra:
$array = changeQuantity($array, "baz", 1);

// Trazando tendras 2 unidades de cada producto (ya que le asigne un incremento 
// de valor de 1 por defecto al producto):
print_r($array);

/*
Array
(
    [foo] => 2
    [baz] => 2
)
*/

// Esta función te permite además incrementar por más de una unidad, o incluso
// restar unidades:
$array = changeQuantity($array, "baz", 5);
$array = changeQuantity($array, "baz", -3);
print_r($array);

/*
Array
(
    [foo] => 2
    [baz] => 4
)
*/
```

Y sólo tendrías que meter el array de productos / cantidades en el de sesión:

```
$_SESSION['carrito'] = $array;
```

Y para ver la cantidad de un producto, por ejemplo "foo":

```
echo $_SESSION['carrito']['foo'];
```

Y para añadir 1 a "foo":

```
$carrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
$carrito = changeQuantity($carrito, "foo", 1);
$_SESSION['carrito'] = $carrito;
```